# How to print utility::string_t type value?

Tags: c++

I need to print the value of contentType variable.

```
void WsListener::handle_put(http_request message)
{

    http_headers& headers = message.headers();
    utility::string_t contentType=headers.content_type();
    cout << (string)contentType;
};
```

Error output

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   'type cast': cannot convert from 'utility::string_t' to 'std::string'   StolenDetailsService    c:\users\nuwanst\source\repos\stolendetailsservice\stolendetailsservice\wslistner.cpp   65  
Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from "utility::string_t" to "std::string" exists    StolenDetailsService    c:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\StolenDetailsService\StolenDetailsService\wsListner.cpp   65
```

Comment: is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Please, 1) include information on the libraries that you are using, since `utility::string_t` is not a standard C++ type, and 2) clearly specify the observed behavior & errors.

Comment: yes this code not working

Comment: Then how to print the value of it. is there any other possible way?

Comment: This is a perfect duplicate. The answer is in the linked question.

Comment: YSC, okay then please figure out the correct answer and comment down please. I'll up vote you.